# How to pass angular login form to spring security

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a CRUD project and I'm attempting to implement an angular frontend, and want to know how to pass the login form to spring security correctly. Currently the post request gets performed, but in the loadUserByUsername method the username is null and I think it has to do with how I'm trying to send the form.

Login form

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin(userForm)">
 
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ngModel placeholder="username">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" ngModel placeholder="password">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

  </div>
</form>
```

Login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  
  constructor(private service:RestapiService, private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  doLogin(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.login(form).subscribe(data=> {
      console.log("logged in")
    },
      error=>console.log("error"));
      
  
    this.router.navigate(["/"]);
  }
}
```

RestapiService.ts

```
export class RestapiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public login(user:NgForm) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/login", user.value, {headers: headers});
  } 

}
```

loadUserByUsername

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        AppUser user = appUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);   
    }
```

I have no mapping in my controller class to /login as I assume spring security automatically allows post requests to the endpoint.

Comment: could you please update and show us what your request looks like in the browser debug network menu (F12)

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't provided  your WebSecurityConfigurations class and the details of how you are making the securityContext, I think You can use JWT mechanism in your login process(if you haven't tried it yet). For this, you should implement a custom authentication filter and put it before your UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in the spring's security filter chain.
From [here](https://www.bezkoder.com/angular-12-spring-boot-jwt-auth/), you can find all about implementing registration + login with JWT in SpringSecurity and Angular. If you follow all steps correctly, there wont be a problem.